# How to get stdout from background?

Tags: linux, terminal, background-process, nohup

Lets assume I have a C++ program producing output all the time like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << (i++)%10 << endl;
    }
}
```

I now want to run this program in the background on a remote linux server. If I do it like this

```
nohup ./program &>/dev/null &
```

then I don't get any output at all. If I do

```
nohup ./program &
```

all the output is written to nohup.out flooding my HDD.

How can I turn off the output while in the background and turn on the output to console while the program is in the foreground ?

Comment: Seems like you are asking to have the process print on a terminal while you are logged onto your remote server, and don't print anywhere when you logout. Can you clarify the difference between "background" and "foreground" in your specific case?

Comment: The process should not print to the terminal all the time I am logged onto the remote server, no. It should not print anywhere until I tell him "show me what's going on". The calculations however have to be done all the time..

Comment: Ok. How do you suppose to tell the program "show me what's going on"? Seems to me like a logic you should put into your program. Or in a wrapper shell script.

Comment: Yeah, exactly this is the question, I am asking for :) Its not possible to change the programm itself.

Comment: Ok, so the terms "background" and "foreground" processing don't really apply here to your question. The process is practically always running, and you start is as a background with `nohup`, and all you want is a way to be able and check on the output whenever you want, avoiding the system HDD to get filled by the log.

Comment: If that's the case, I can only think of using a `logrotate`-like approach, and when you want to see what's going on, you'd `tail` on the logfile. That's how much I can help with. Hope the clarifications will help others get you more useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but you could link `nohup.out` to `/dev/null` and remove the link to turn on logging into the file.

create a symbolic link:
`ln -s /dev/null nohup.out`

remove the link:
`rm nohup.out`

If nohup does not create the logfile after you deleted the link you may have to create it with

`touch nohup.out`